# Joining tables in Powerpivot

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerpivot

I have two tables: 'Sales' and 'Planed sales'. They represent sales data for about 80 different products and planed sales for those products across two months for every day. This is how they look:

Table 'Sales'

| productName | Sold | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product_A | 10 | 01.01.2022. |
| product_B | 15 | 01.01.2022. |
| product_A | 11 | 02.01.2022. |
| product_B | 20 | 02.01.2022. |

And then table 'Planed sales'

| productName | Planed sales | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product_A | 10 | 01.01.2022. |
| product_B | 14 | 01.01.2022. |
| product_A | 9 | 02.01.2022. |
| product_B | 15 | 02.01.2022. |

Product names are same in both tables and so are the dates, only 'Sold' and 'Planed sales' data differs.
I somehow need to use these two tables in a SQL query for Power Pivot in Excel while I'm importing data so I can get a table looking something  like this:

| productName | Planed sales 01.01. | Sold 01.01. | Planned sales 02.01. | Sold 02.01. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product_A | 10 | 10 | 9 | 11 |
| product_B | 14 | 15 | 15 | 20 |

I have lots of different products and a lot of dates for at least two months.

I tried to just import both of these tables in Excels power pivot with a simple 'select *' query, and then create a relationship, but I don't have unique values because productName is displayed for every date. Unique key here would be 'productName' + 'Date', but I don't know how to add composite key in Excels Power Pivot if that is the solution for this. I know data is not well normalized but I can't change it much, it is what it is. Am I approaching this problem correctly? Is this even possible? If it is, how could I do it?

Comment: This *looks* like you want a dynamic pivot; this is something that is normally best done in your application. So return a normalised dataset to the application, and pivot that as required.

Comment: You *can* create a calculated column in each table in the data model that concatenates the date and the product and then use that for the relationship. I'd probably use Power Query and append the datasets, adding a Type column ("Planned" and "Sold"), then just pivot on that.

Comment: @Larnu, when you say application, do you mean MS SQL Server or Excel?

Comment: I mean what ever application is consuming the data, @AndrejaZivanovic, which isn't SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Product dimension. There's a lot of help on the web on dimensional modeling for Power BI and PowerPivot. It's worth learning.

Add a table that is just a list of all the unique productNames and then add a relationship from this new table to your 2 existing tables.

If you have a data source with the product list, use that. If you don't, combine the two tables and remove duplicates. You can do this in either DAX or Power Query, but Power Query would be the better way to do this.

In Power Query, append the 2 tables (**Home > Append Queries**), then right click the productName column and **Remove Other Columns**, and right click again to **Remove Duplicates**.

Then go into PowerPivot to create the relationships. In your pivot, use productName from the Product dimension, not from the other 2 tables. Best practice is to right click the productName column in those 2 tables and hide them to make sure the correct table is used.